# Search for installed applications execution path

Tags: search, shortcuts, file-search, application-launch

I do not only want to find what is installed, but also show the path to execute the application as results of my search.

So I thought about using `dpkg -l` combined with the `which` command.
I would like to make a script that checks the path for still installed GUI applications and show the execution path in order to make or verify existend .desktop files for each.

Would this be applicable ?

Execution path examples in the Cinnamon 5.2.7 menu :

- `protontricks --no-term --gui`
- `env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/spotify_spotify.desktop /snap/bin/spotify %U`
- `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=*some long id here corresponding to my gmail*`
- `wine C:/windows/notepad.exe`
- `/usr/sbin/gparted %f`
- `pkexec lightdm-settings`
- `dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.Cinnamon /org/Cinnamon org.Cinnamon.ToggleKeyboard`

There are many possibilities. So I think I'll start to comfirm with typical applications first, like gedit.

`wich gedit` output:

```
/usr/bin/gedit
```

I did: `dpkg -l |awk '/^[hi]i/{print $2}' > installation.txt`

But this didn't list only GUI application. I was thinking I could compare the output with the `.desktop` files contained in `/usr/share/applications`.

So I was wondering how to apply the output variables of installation.txt on the which command?

`which | cat installation.txt` does only list what's in the file. This was solved with the command: `xargs < installation.txt which`

*Since I solved my problem by upgrading my desktop environment I do not require a specific answer to this post anymore.*

---

References:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/60826/where-is-the-default-folder-for-apps

Source problem:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450586/uninstalled-applications-arent-automatically-removed-from-the-cinnamon-menu

Answer (score 1):

The issue with using which is that it will find binaries that are not all graphical applications, and many of those won't work well with a .desktop file or might need special options in the desktop file.  Even with system desktop files, there is not a 1:1 correspondence between binaries in your path and desktop files -- there may be multiple desktop files for the same binary and not all binaries have a desktop file at all.

Instead of which, it might be better to use `dpkg -L packages... | grep desktop`  and find out where it saved the system copy of the desktop files.

As I already posted in the other question, a better solution might be to just purge (or better, rename) your local account applications folder and let it get rebuilt.

Comment: But this is a one by one solution. I'm lookin for a why to update/verify the Cinnamon shortcuts all at ones. 
Is there a chance I could use the ~/.local/share/applications/ location to make a script that would search for the outdated .desktop files ? (reference)

Comment: That's a different question.  The .desktop files contain one or more Exec lines and you could check if the first path on those lines still exist.  Also probably could do that with the icon line.

Comment: It's worth the try I think. You'll find some of the exec path in the link provided in the source problem. The goal would be to search if the executable or its path still exists. This seem applicable in most cases ... But since it's related with, if it's installed or not, the dpkg option was logic to me. To get the exec path I recently found the advice to use which.

Comment: The rebuild does not mach with all the installed applications. It sets the Cinnamon menu by default.